# ¿Como puedo unir una imagen convertida a escala de gris con una imagen de color en python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv

El código lo hice para fusionar imágenes, una a escala de gris y otra a colores normales, pero hay algo mal:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img1 = cv2.imread('E:\prueba1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img2 = cv2.imread('E:\prueba2.jpg')
tamaño1 = cv2.resize(gray, (320,280))
tamaño2 = cv2.resize(img2, (320,280))
dst = cv2.addWeighted(tamaño1, 0.7, tamaño2, 0.5, 0)
cv2.imshow('mezcla',dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

El error es el siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:663:
error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match)
The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), 
nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'cv::arithm_op'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que `addWeighted()` necesita que ambas imágenes sean del mismo tamaño *y de la misma profundidad de color*, es decir, que usen el mismo número de bits por pixel. La imagen en tonos de gris usa 8 bits por pixel, mientras que la imagen en colores rgb usa 24 (8 bits por cada componente de color).

La solución es convertir la imagen de tonos de gris a rgb. Naturalmente eso no recuperará los colores originales (que se pierden en la conversión a grises), sino que dará el mismo valor a las tres componentes (r, g, b) de cada pixel.

Así:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img1 = cv2.imread('prueba1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img2 = cv2.imread('prueba2.jpg')
tamaño1 = cv2.resize(gray, (320,280))
tamaño2 = cv2.resize(img2, (320,280))

tamaño1_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(tamaño1, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB) # <-----

dst = cv2.addWeighted(tamaño1_rgb, 0.7, tamaño2, 0.5, 0)
cv2.imshow('mezcla',dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Por ejemplo, si `prueba1.jpg` es esta:

[image: python]

y `prueba2.jpg` es esta:

[image: python-logo]

el resultado de ejecutar tu código será:

[image: resultado]

Answer (score 1):

El propio error te da la clave de forma un poco velada:

> The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), 
>   nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'cv::arithm_op'

lo que podemos traducir como:

> La operación no es  'array op array' (donde los arrays tienen el mismo tamaño y el mismo número de canales), ni 'array op escalar' o 'escalar op array' en la función 'cv :: arithm_op'

La clave es "donde los arrays tienen el mismo tamaño y el mismo número de canales", en tu caso tienes un array (`tamaño1`) de (280, 320), escala de grises (monocanal), mientras que `tamaño2` tiene una disensiones de (280, 320, 3), BGR (tricanal). Para que `cv2.addWeighted` pueda funcionar, ambos arrays deben tener las mismas dimensiones, en el fondo no es más que una suma ponderada de matrices.

Puedes conseguirlo de varias formas, desde hacer la conversión inversa de escala de grises a BGR en algún momento previo a aplicar `cv2.addWeighted` o usar `np.stack` directamente:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


img1 = cv2.imread('E:\prueba1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#bgr_gray = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
bgr_gray = np.stack((gray,) * 3, axis=-1)

img2 = cv2.imread('E:\prueba2.jpg')
tamaño1 = cv2.resize(bgr_gray, (320,280))
tamaño2 = cv2.resize(img2, (320,280))
dst = cv2.addWeighted(tamaño1, 0.7, tamaño2, 0.5, 0)
cv2.imshow('mezcla',dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```